# How to get the protection level for each permission?

Tags: android, permissions

Im trying to list the protection level for each permission in the selected application, for the code given below. But i do not know how to get it done.

```
ArrayList<String> list_permission = new ArrayList<String>();
        String[] reqp = info.requestedPermissions;
        if (reqp != null) {
            for (i = 0; i < reqp.length; i++) {

                k = i + 1;

                String a = reqp[i];
                if (a.contains("android.permission.")) {
                    String aa[] = a.split("android.permission.");
                    list_permission.add(aa[1]);
                } else {
                    list_permission.add(a);
                }

            }

        }
```

can anyone help me with this... just want to add the protection level in front of the permission.

Comment: do you want to check permission level of installed package ? If yes then check this API http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html#protectionLevel

Comment: http://rupertrawnsley.blogspot.de/2011/11/android-permissions-protection-levels.html even this give the whole permission protection levels... but do not know how to code it for the app im doing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [PackageManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html) class [getPermissionInfo()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getPermissionInfo%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method to get [PermissionInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html) object for any particular permission. [PermissionInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html) object has property [Protection Lavel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html#protectionLevel) that can be used to check the protection level of any permission... You can check it against the constant defined in the [PermissoinInfo](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html) class like  `PROTECTION_FLAG_SYSTEM`.

Like following code :

```
for (PermissionInfo permission : packageInfo.permissions) {
    // Dump permission info
    String protectionLevel;
    switch(permission.protectionLevel) {
    case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_NORMAL : protectionLevel = "normal"; break;
    case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_DANGEROUS : protectionLevel = "dangerous"; break;
    case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_SIGNATURE : protectionLevel = "signature"; break;
    case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_SIGNATURE_OR_SYSTEM : protectionLevel = "signatureOrSystem"; break;
    default : protectionLevel = "<unknown>"; break;
    }
    Log.i("PermissionCheck", permission.name + " " + protectionLevel);
  }
```

**UPDATE**:

To get the Protection level of `requestedPermissions`:

```
String[] reqp = info.requestedPermissions;
String perm = reqp[i];
if (perm.contains("android.permission.")) {
    try {
        PermissionInfo pi = getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(perm, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        String protctionLevel = "unknown";

        switch(pi.protectionLevel) {
            case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_NORMAL : protctionLevel = "normal"; break;
            case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_DANGEROUS : protctionLevel = "dangerous"; break;
            case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_SIGNATURE : protctionLevel = "signature"; break;
            case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_SIGNATURE_OR_SYSTEM : protctionLevel = "signatureOrSystem"; break;
            case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_FLAG_SYSTEM : protctionLevel = "system"; break;
            default : protctionLevel = "<unknown>"; break;
        }
        list_permission.add(perm + "        "+protctionLevel);
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

} else {
    list_permission.add(perm);
}
```

Following line would only work on API level 16 or above:

```
        case PermissionInfo.PROTECTION_FLAG_SYSTEM : protctionLevel = "system"; break;
```

Comment: so it gives as intiger values as 0,1,2,3 so 0 is normal, 1 is dangerous, 2 is signature, 3 is system?

Comment: dont use the int value use compare the return value with the constant  defined in the PermissionInfo class to check the protection level similar to the link you have shared...

Comment: the code in the link you shared was good enough... let me know if you have any specific problem in that code...

Comment: yah well i tried that, but do not know how to get that permission protection levels to the selected permissions of reqp[i]. that is the problem im facing

Comment: anw, further if i want to change the color of the protection level, as red and blue how can i do that.... "dangerous"(red) kinda

Comment: Are all that marked as "dangerous" considered as runtime-permissions and only them, meaning we can request them using the same API and check if they are granted using the same API ?