# Get permission details programmatically

Tags: android, android-permissions

Is there anyway in android sdk where they provide an information for specific permission? Like how google play does, whenever you click on a permission you are able to read what does this permission do. I have this function to return me specific permissions for an application

```
public static List<String> getAppPermissions(Context context, String packageName) {
    try {
        PackageInfo info = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
        return Arrays.asList(info.requestedPermissions);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
}
```

By this code im getting only permission names, but I'm wondering if there is any such  api that return permissions and their details.

Comment: That may answer the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13523859/how-to-get-the-protection-level-for-each-permission

Comment: @Markus Marvell nope that didn't help. That will only tell you the permission level

Comment: as so as label, description, icon etc. i.e. all you can take from PermissionInfo class. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PermissionInfo.html

Comment: @Markus Marvell, well definitely it does, im just curious how i never checked out that class.  I will give a try on weekend and see how it does work. Thanks buddy for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to answer my question, `PermissionInfo` is actually the right `class` to get a description about any `android permission` for example:

```
@Nullable
public static PermissionInfo getPermissionInfo(@NonNull Context context, @NonNull String permission) {
    try {
        return context.getPackageManager().getPermissionInfo(permission, PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

above method will return `PermissionInfo` instance if it could parse the `permission` name given to it, and then simply you could call `loadDescription` to load the `permission` description.